# How to scrape instagram post URL's using puppeteer (Node.js applicatie)

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

With all the changes to the current Instagram API I was trying to build a scraper. After some looking around I found puppeteer. Although it seems really straightforward I am running into a problem I can't seem to wrap my head around.

The problem is the following:
I know what the div tag of a post is `(.v1Nh3.kIKUG._bz0w)` and how to call for it `(elements = await page.$$('.v1Nh3.kIKUG._bz0w');)`

If I understand the $ function correctly this should return me a promise containing an array of all the posts on 'page'.

My first question would be if this assumption is correct, and my second is how I can get the array out of. (And if that all works how to get the redirect URL contained in the child href)

Comment: You need to use the [page.evaluate](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.20.0&show=api-pageevaluatepagefunction-args) method which does return a Promise

Comment: as in wrap my page pall into it, or do I need to rewrite my previous code?

Comment: Hey @A-Daneel, please see another answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first: since Instagram is a heavy javascript-powered React application, the selectors you are after may not be available right after the page is loaded. So we should wait for them to appear in the DOM:

```
await page.waitForSelector('.v1Nh3.kIKUG._bz0w');
```

Now with page.evaluate we get the posts, but since you only want the links inside of those posts, let's grab them right away in the query:

```
const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
    // Get elements into a NodeList
    const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.v1Nh3.kIKUG._bz0w a');
    ...
}
```

But we cant convert the elements from Nodelist to an Array and just return them, because they're still DOM nodes, complex unserializable objects, and they need to be [serializable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Description) to be able to return from `page.evaluate`. So instead of returning the complete nodes we'll just get what we need: urls from href attribute:

```
const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
    // Get elements into a NodeList
    const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.v1Nh3.kIKUG._bz0w a');

    // Convert elements to an array, 
    // then for each item of that array only return the href attribute
    const linksArr = Array.from(elements).map(link => link.href);

    return linksArr;
});
```

**Other ways to do it**

In your question you mentioned `page.$$` method. It is indeed applicable here to get *handles* of the objects we seek. But the code to iterate over them is not pretty:

```
const results = await page.$$('.v1Nh3.kIKUG._bz0w a')
for (const i in results)
{
   console.log(await(await(await results[i]).getProperty("href")).jsonValue());
}
```

My favourite way to get those links though would be to use `page.$$eval` method:

```
const results = await page.$$eval('.v1Nh3.kIKUG._bz0w a', links => links.map(link => link.href))
```

It does exactly the same what we did in `page.evaluate` solution but in a much more concise way.

Comment: well, fist off thanks for the tip that there could be some time between opening the page and all the elements being present! That has put this problem in a whole new light. After this I could just iterate over result to get all the links. right? like this: `var resultArr = result;
(for url in resultArr){
    console.log(url)
}`

Comment: You don't even need to reassign result, it is already an array of links, you can interate over it, yes!

Comment: excelt the fact  that I needed to log `result[url]` it worked. and better then that, I understand why. Thnx!

Comment: what exactly is the added benefit of the $$eval method, besides it only being one line?

Comment: It's just another `convenience` method, it's handy exactly for such simple one-liners. For all the other stuff I use good old `page.evaluate`.

Comment: @Vaviloff Hey man. Could you please help me with my issue? I'm trying to fetch all the ```href``` values from the first post in a Facebook group feed. Each post has class ``` div[role="feed"] .du4w35lb``` and anchor links are way too deep inside. How can I choose the first ``` div[role="feed"] .du4w35lb``` and fetch the href values?

Comment: @s.khan Cheers man! Could you create a new question with puppeteer tag? I'd be happy to have a look at it then!

Comment: @Vaviloff bro here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67269499/how-can-i-fetch-the-post-link-in-a-facebook-group-post-div-by-selecting-it-out-o

Answer (score 1):

In order to get elements with a certain class and return them you must use the [page.evaluate](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.20.0&show=api-pageevaluatepagefunction-args) method. This is an asynchronous call which returns a promise.

So, in your use case, it should look like this:

```
const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
    let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.v1Nh3.kIKUG._bz0w');

    let elementsArr = [];
    //Loop over elements in the array and create objects from each element 
    //with the data relevant to your logic
    for (let element of elements) {
        resultArr.push({
           //your logic
        });
    }
    return elementsArr;
});
```

Comment: Looked into the evaluate function. think I've tried something similar before.
Is it correct that I cant use any logs inside an evaluate?

I would assume the result would have a typeof 'Array', however it resolves to undefined. Now, if I understand the docs correctly this would happen if the evaluate resolves to nothing. however when I use the query on the chrome console it highlights the expected posts. Any idea what I might be missing?

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code (without logs) using [debugger](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_debugging.asp)? Do you navigate to the correct page using puppeteer?

Comment: I am sure about being on the right page, since the action before the scaping is moving downwards on the page and I can see that happening. As for the debugger, I have tried using it but not to much success. I'll read up on your link and try to get a bit further with debugging.

Comment: @tomerpacific, I'm afraid your answer is not correct. You can't just return DOM nodes from page.evaluate, even in an array.

Comment: @Vaviloff - You are correct. I have edited my answer.

Comment: @tomerpacific, great, but still there's a small glitch in the code :)

Comment: @tomerpacific Hey man. Could you please help me with my issue? I'm trying to fetch all the href values from the first post in a Facebook group feed. Each post has class ``` div[role="feed"] .du4w35lb``` and anchor links are way too deep inside. How can I choose the first ``` div[role="feed"] .du4w35lb``` and fetch the href values?