# How can I fetch the post link in a Facebook Group post div by selecting it out of multiple divs?

Tags: puppeteer

So I'm working on this puppeteer app which requires me to fetch the post link in a Facebook Group post, especially the link of the post which is the `time and date` of the post below the author name. And I want to fetch that post link only for the first post only.

So to do that I have to start by selecting the outermost div of the post which is the parent. And apparently each post in the feed contains the same class as shown in this photo:

[image]

The photo above shows a typical html  structure of Facebook feed. The first child div is the `New Activity` title div. And the other children are post divs. I'm only interested in the first post div which is `Post 1` in the picture above.

The anchor link I'm interested in is nested deep inside. Probably 10-15 levels deep. And there are probably a million anchor links. So to narrow it down I can target to fetch links only in the header of the post.

[image]

The image below shows the structure of the parent div and the header div:
[image]

This image shows which link I'm trying to fetch.
[image]

I know the pictures above are just too overwhelming but this is the simplest way I could explain what I have been trying to do. The problem is I'm unable to use the actual selectors. I'm new to Puppeteer and its syntax is a little bit complicated for me. So in simplest terms what I want from you is select the first `Post 1` div out of multiple same class divs. This is the most important part. Then choosing the inner divs with classes to the actual anchor link.

Beside all the codes I have tried this is one of them:

```
const postDivs = await page.$$( 'div[role="feed"] .du4w35lb' );

const hrefs = await page.$$eval( `${postDivs[ 0 ]} .pybr56ya .buofh1pr a`, links => links.map( a => a.href ) );

console.log( 'anchor link: ', hrefs );
```

The above code returns an error that says:

```
Error: Evaluation failed: DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on
'Document': 'JSHandle@node .pybr56ya .buofh1pr a' is not a valid selector.
```

Hoping to get a positive reply from you.

*****************UPDATE********************
This is the code I'm using to **scrape** the anchor links:

```
( async () => {
    try {

        const browser = await puppeteer.launch( {
            headless: false,
            args: [ '--no-sandbox', '--allow-third-party-modules', '--start-maximized' ],
            slowMo: 10
        } );

        const context = await browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext();
        const page = await context.newPage();

        // go to webpage
        await page.goto( 'https://www.facebook.com', { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' } );

        // fill login details and submit
        await page.waitForSelector( "#email" );
        await page.focus( "#email" );
        await page.type( "#email", "myEmailId", { delay: 50 } );
        await page.waitForSelector( "#pass" );
        await page.focus( "#pass" );
        await page.type( "#pass", "myPassword", { delay: 50 } );
        await page.click( `[type="submit"]` );

        await page.waitForNavigation();
        await page.goto( "https://www.facebook.com/groups/groupName", { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' } );


        await page.waitForTimeout( 5000 );

        // code to fetch the links
        const links = await page.evaluate( function () {
            return [ ...document.querySelectorAll( 'div[role=feed] .du4w35lb .buofh1pr .tojvnm2t .oajrlxb2[role=link]' ) ].map( ( link ) => link.href );
        } );

        console.log( 'links: ', links );

        await page.waitForTimeout( 5000 );


        // close browser
        await browser.close()


    } catch ( err ) {
        console.log( err );
    }
} )();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to find a selector that is unique enough to only pick out what you need. To do that you may try to string together classes from several levels leading to the link with the date (but not leading to other links, like profile links, hence "uniqe enough").

I did a quick experiment on a random FB discussion group where selectors are currently very similar to yours and came up with this selector to find the links to posts:

```
const links = await page.evaluate(function(){
  return [...document.querySelectorAll('div[role=feed] .du4w35lb .buofh1pr .tojvnm2t .oajrlxb2[role=link]')].map((link) => link.href);
});
```

It should produce an array like this:

```
[
  "https://www.facebook.com/groups/somegroup/permalink/1244304367068568/?__cft__[0]=AZXxG8lKJxPS9bC&__tn__=%2CO%2CP-R",
  "https://www.facebook.com/groups/somegroup/permalink/1243163367516017/?__cft__[0]=AZXcER8tI9lU1EL&__tn__=%2CO%2CP-R",
  "https://www.facebook.com/groups/somegroup/permalink/1245602367605409/?__cft__[0]=AZW9cets_p3QIyB&__tn__=%2CO%2CP-R",
  "https://www.facebook.com/groups/somegroup/permalink/1248223367343307/?__cft__[0]=AZV-htDstk_4Gsn&__tn__=%2CO%2CP-R",
  "https://www.facebook.com/groups/somegroup/permalink/1247711367061195/?__cft__[0]=AZW2depBCCmRtXC&__tn__=%2CO%2CP-R",
  "https://www.facebook.com/groups/somegroup#",
  "https://www.facebook.com/groups/somegroup#"
]
```

Notice the two last elements though: obviously you need to hover a cursor over the date link for FB to dynamically calculate the href, so keep that in mind.

Comment: Hey. Thanks so much for your time. I tried your code. The selectors are same for all Facebook groups. But I'm not getting that array with "permalink" links. All I'm getting is an array of 6 of these links: ```'https://www.facebook.com/groups/groupname#'```. Also please check my post above for the full code I'm using to scrap the data.

Comment: You probably didn't notice I mentioned that: "obviously you need to hover a cursor over the date link for FB to dynamically calculate the href". Probably there are other ways to collect those links, this post answers your question on how to find selectors for the links.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice. I figured it out btw. Used page.hover() before scraping the links. Thanks a lot for your help. Another thing is, as you're an expert in Puppeteer, may I knock you with issues, if I face any, in the future? I'll create the question beforehand.

Comment: There are many people here who I really consider experts in Puppeteer  but sure, ping me if you want in the future

Comment: Hey. Sorry to bother you again. But there's an issue which needs your expertise. Here's the link to the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67304665/puppeteer-page-type-misses-out-first-couple-of-characters-of-the-string

Answer (score 0):

In order to fetch the post Link, facebook is complex as its tricks to hide the data and build lot of DOM values dynamically.

1. we need to hover on the date time under author name
2. It will generate the required link as attribute value to href, which you can reach through inspect element.

Below code should work but you might have to update the CSS selectors.

searchResults is the elementHandle for each posts in the list.

```
 try {
          let date_time_button = await searchResult.$(
            ".x1iyjqo2 .x1nxh6w3[dir=auto] [role=link]"
          );

          if (date_time_button != null) await date_time_button.hover();
          //if (date_time_button != null) await date_time_button.evaluate((b: any) => b.hover());
        } catch (err) {
          console.log("Error in Hovering Date Time to fetch Post link Url");
        }

        await sleep(1000);
        let permalink: string = await searchResult.$eval(
          ".x1iyjqo2 .x1nxh6w3[dir=auto] [role=link]",
          (anchor: any) => anchor.getAttribute("href")
        );
        post.permalink = permalink.split("?")[0];
```