# Puppeteer: page.type() misses out first couple of characters of the string

Tags: puppeteer

I am facing an issue with Puppeteer's `page.type()` method. Sometimes it types a whole string perfectly but at times it just misses out the first couple of characters.

Suppose I have a string: `I may not be there yet but I am closer than yesterday`. It just types `y not be there yet but I am closer than yesterday`.

I have found an [issue](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1648) in github related to this but it has been closed. Although I have tried some of the solutions suggested there but it doesn't seem to work. I have also asked in the issue to be reopened but I guess it will take some time.

So thought of seeking a solution from SO. Here's the code:

```
const blog = {
     postContent: [
          {
               text: "SSBtYXkgbm90IGJlIHRoZXJlIHlldCwgYnV0IEknbSBjbG9zZXIgdGhhbiB5ZXN0ZXJkYXk=",
               status: "pending"
          },
          {
               text: "RG9uJ3QgcXVpdGUuIFN1ZmZlciBub3cgYW5kIGxpdmUgdGhlIHJlc3Qgb2YgeW91ciBsaWZlIGFzIGEgY2hhbXBpb24u",
               status: "pending"
          },
          {
               text: "TGlmZSBpcyBub3QgYWJvdXQgd2lubmluZy4gSXQncyBhYm91dCBub3QgZ2l2aW5nIHVwIQ==",
               status: "pending"
          }
     ]
};


await page.waitForSelector('div[role="presentation"]' );
await page.focus('div[role="presentation"]');

// finding the index of the blog post which is pending
const pendingPostIndex = await blog.postContent.findIndex( item => item.status === "pending" );

// decoding post content
const textContent = `${Buffer.from(blog.postContent[pendingPostIndex].text, 'base64').toString()}`;

// this gets the full text without missing characters
console.log('text content of pending post: ', textContent);

// first couple characters are missing most of the time
await page.type('div[role="presentation"] span', textContent, {
         delay: 100
});
```

I don't know what could be going wrong here. Is it because decoding takes a little bit of time and page.type() fires before the text is completely decoded? Or finding the post index takes time? How can I fix this?

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant but wonder why you're typing into a span.

Comment: It was ```div[role=presentation] span```. But to make it simpler I changed this to ```input[type=text] span```. I'll change it back to what it is actually. It's the Facebook's input field. There's no input element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A suggestion mentioned on the issue page you cited, and that has also worked for me is to be sure the input is zeroed out before typing:

```
await page.click('div[role="presentation"] span', {clickCount: 3});
await page.keyboard.press('Backspace');
```

Comment: thanks a lot mate. I first tried with the above code. But it didn't work in my case. Then I removed 'span' and added ```delay: 100```. Now it seems to be working but I'm not sure if its totally fixed or the issue will arise again as it used to happen randomly. I'll update here if the issue arises again.